# Visual Studio Alignment Errors For WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015

I'm unsure if this problem is on account of Visual Studio 2015 or on account of my computer.

In WPF, the default margin between a control and the edge of a window is 10 pixels. If I add a button, depending on the width, the following can happen where the right border (of the button) won't show.

http://s2.postimg.org/ilaz0r0ft/image.png

(I don't have enough rep to post images)

If I align that same button on the right side, it will make the right margin 9.6, not 10 and all the borders will show.

http://s10.postimg.org/60g17cbah/image.png

Of course, if I edit the XAML, I can make the margins proper, but anytime I touch that button in the designer, it will go back to what it was.

This can be very frustrating for me and I'm curious to know if there is a solution and if anyone else has experienced such a problem.

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Community and I have an ASUS K501LX with a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M graphics card.

Comment: Just never use the XAML designer :) Most of WPF developers write XAML markup directly.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev I suppose you're right. But I also feel like designers take tedious work and make it quick.

Comment: I use the designer all the time for projects, and the designer in Blend too.  The VS 2015 designer is better than the earlier editions.  More respectful of your hand written XAML

Comment: I'm not seeing the 9.6 right margin when aligning to the right.  I defaults to 10. I tested on two computers.

Comment: @WaltRitscher It must be my computer. I'm not surprised, my graphics card has caused many problems for me (very frustrating). Thank you for confirming this for me!